# Sharing a Pool object across processes in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, shared-memory, process-pool

I am trying to share a pool object between multiple processes using the following code

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import time
pool = Pool(5)
def print_hello():
    time.sleep(1)
    return "hello"
def pipeline():
    print("In pipeline")
    msg = pool.apply_async(print_hello()).get(timeout=1.5)
    print("In pipeline")
    print(msg)
def post():
    p = Process(target = pipeline)
    p.start()
    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    post()
    print("Returned from post")
```

However the code exists with the timout since get() doesnot return. I believe this has to do with pool being a globally accessible variable because it works just fine when I move pool to being local to pipeline function. Can anyone give me suggestions if there exists a workaround for this problem ?

Edit: finally got working with thread instead of process for running pipeline function.

Comment: There's no point trying to share the Pool to child processes. What's your end goal here?

Comment: I want to make a pipeline such that for every request a pipeline is fired. Inside the pipeline I have multiple subjobs. Say j1 and j2. Now I want all atmax 5 j1 jobs to be running so creating a pool of j1 type jobs. When my j1 job of the pipeline finishes I want my j2 job to be fired in a separate pool of processes allowing max 10 worker processes. I don't see how to achieve this without using 2 pools (for j1 and j2) shared between multiple pipelines (or processes).

Comment: Well, why not use a single master process and two pools then? If you want to use a single pool, you can just make it large enough for all tasks, then keep track of how many tasks of each type is currently running and wait until there's "space".

Comment: The problem is I can't even use a single pool (the code would then look like the above sample I posted). I don't want my post to be blocking. Hence I fire another subprocess and return immediately. Now this subprocess handles firing j1 and subsequently j2 on completion of j1.

Comment: @HardikAggarwal According to your description, you are already creating a subprocess for every `post`. So why not start the jobs `j1`  and `j2` there and then in the pipeline function itself instead of using a pool?

Comment: @Charchit I already did mention that I need a pool because I need to limit my number of active worker processes. Also j1 and j2 are sequential processes so they cannot be started simultaneously in pipeline function.